# Android MediaPlayer: prepared video takes 250ms to start playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I play a video, using prepareAsync(), then calling start() when the video is prepared, it takes about 250ms from my start() call to when the video actually starts to play. Is that just how it is, or is something funny going on here? Note that the video is in the raw directory. In my activity's OnCreate I have:

```
private VideoView vv;
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv);
vv.getHolder().addCallback(this);
mp.reset();
mp.setDisplay( vv.getHolder() );
mp.setDataSource( this, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.moviename) );
Log.d(TAG,"video is preparing");
mp.prepareAsync();
```

Then there is the listener:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
   Log.d(TAG, "video is prepared");
   mp.start();
}
```

Actually my code is more complicated than this. The user clicks a button to play the video and can also select different videos. I have an image hiding the video, and at a certain number of ms from mp.start() I pull this image away and reveal the video. On my device I have to set this at 250ms to reliably not reveal something other than the video (that something is either black or the last frame of the previous video played).

What I'm wondering is whether you can tell from my logcat that something is not right with this. I'm curious about the messages that aren't titled ButtonBookActivity. Are they normal? These are mp4s. Note that preparing the video in this case takes only 120ms.

```
04-15 13:30:05.600: D/ButtonBookActivity(1238): video is reset
04-15 13:30:05.620: I/NuCachedSource2(83): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
04-15 13:30:05.630: D/AwesomePlayer(83): Failed to open file, all profile flags have to set through setprop method.
04-15 13:30:05.630: I/MPEG4Extractor(83):  NON-QT MODE DECIDED 
04-15 13:30:05.640: I/SampleTable(83): There are reordered frames present.
04-15 13:30:05.640: D/ButtonBookActivity(1238): video is preparing
04-15 13:30:05.640: I/OMXCodec(83): [OMX.Nvidia.h264.decode] AVC profile = 77 (Main), level = 32
04-15 13:30:05.640: I/OMXCodec(83): [OMX.Nvidia.h264.decode] video dimensions are 800 x 1280
04-15 13:30:05.640: I/OMXCodec(83): [OMX.Nvidia.h264.decode] Crop rect is 800 x 1280 @ (0, 0)
04-15 13:30:05.760: D/ButtonBookActivity(1238): video is prepared
04-15 13:30:06.540: D/ButtonBookActivity(1238): touch event
04-15 13:30:06.540: D/ButtonBookActivity(1238): button clicked
04-15 13:30:06.550: D/ButtonBookActivity(1238): calling playmovie in onTouch callback
04-15 13:30:06.550: D/ButtonBookActivity(1238): playing movie
04-15 13:30:06.550: D/ButtonBookActivity(1238): delaying movie reveal
04-15 13:30:06.560: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(83): Allocating new output: 800x1280 (x 12)
04-15 13:30:06.570: I/OMXCodec(83): [OMX.Nvidia.h264.decode] video dimensions are 800 x 1280
04-15 13:30:06.570: I/OMXCodec(83): [OMX.Nvidia.h264.decode] Crop rect is 800 x 1280 @ (0, 0)
04-15 13:30:06.620: D/ButtonBookActivity(1238): touch event
04-15 13:30:06.620: D/ButtonBookActivity(1238): ignoring touch event
04-15 13:30:06.770: V/NvAudioALSA(83): open called for devices 00000002 in mode 0...
04-15 13:30:06.770: V/NvAudioALSA(83): getAlsaDeviceName::devices 0x2 IsVoiceCallDevice 0 devName music
04-15 13:30:06.770: V/NvAudioALSA(83): Reset buffer size to 4096 and latency to 92879
04-15 13:30:06.770: V/NvAudioALSA(83): Set PLAYBACK PCM format to S16_LE (Signed 16 bit Little Endian)
04-15 13:30:06.770: V/NvAudioALSA(83): Using 2 channels for PLAYBACK.
04-15 13:30:06.770: V/NvAudioALSA(83): Set PLAYBACK sample rate to 44100 HZ
04-15 13:30:06.770: V/NvAudioALSA(83): Buffer size: 4096
04-15 13:30:06.770: V/NvAudioALSA(83): Period size: 1024
04-15 13:30:06.770: V/NvAudioALSA(83): Latency: 92879
04-15 13:30:06.770: V/NvAudioALSA(83): Period Time: 23219
04-15 13:30:06.770: V/NvAudioALSA(83): Periods: 4
04-15 13:30:07.060: V/NvAudioALSA(83): Initialized ALSA PLAYBACK device music
04-15 13:30:09.550: D/ButtonBookActivity(1238): video completed
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I'm also interested in whatever answer you may come up with.  I am getting similar messages trying to play a local mp4 in a WebView <video> element, followed by a segfault in some native code.   https://gist.github.com/2606921   It's intermittent and not really reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3434) could be related to the android audio latency problem.
The call to start() for an audio file needs some time, before there is actually sound coming out of the speakers. Perhaps this also applies to videos and the mediaplayer needs some time before it shows any videoframes.

So probably there is nothing you can do.