# Android MediaPlayer `Prepared` and `OnPlayStarted` questions

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Two questions:

Without subclassing, is it possible to tell directly from a `MediaPlayer` instance whether it is in the `Prepared` state or not -- or even get it's state at all? I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058073/android-java-mediaplayer-service-how-can-i-know-if-mediaplayer-is-prepared) and gone through the [MediaPlayer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), and it appears there is no way. I suspect that my only way out is to subclass, but I would like to avoid it if at all possible.

Second, I have read there can be [latency between `OnPreparedListener` and playback actually beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165972/android-mediaplayer-prepared-video-takes-250ms-to-start-playing?s=1|2.3246). Is there a way to tell when a `MediaPlayer` instance has started playback of a local file? I've tried hooking into the listeners for `OnBufferingUpdateListener`, `OnInfoListener`, and `OnSeekCompleteListener`, but they do not appear to be triggered at all after invoking `start()` for local files. Aside from polling to see if `getCurrentPosition()` has changed (admittedly a stupid idea), I can't see any way to see if this is even possible.

Comment: For anyone looking for a Xamarin solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414907/xamarin-forms-android-video-videoview-black-flash-on-page-load-or-back-key-l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question: I don't think that `MediaPlayer` itself maintains a current state, or atleast I have never come across anything as such, even the sample apps I downloaded used a wrapper or subclassing and maintained state of the `MediaPlayer`. I have done the same in my app.

To answer your second question you could use `MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START` in your `OnInfoListener` callback but only for API 17 and above. According to the docs

> ```
> MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START
> ```
>
> The player just pushed the very first video frame for rendering.

Comment: Thanks for this. Sadly, I am using an audio file, and `onInfo()` is never called. I guess I will subclass MediaPlayer, and I hope that latency is never an issue (not a show-stopper, but still an annoyance).

Comment: This solution converted to Xamarin Forms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414907/xamarin-forms-android-video-videoview-black-flash-on-page-load-or-back-key-l